# How to read from set of arrays line by line in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

My code is as follows:

```
private static ArrayList<String[]> file;

...

void method()
{
  file = new ArrayList<String[]>();
  ...
  String[] s = str.split(";");
  file.add(s);
}
```

In the above, `str` is a long String that is seperated by semicolons.

My problem is that I want to go through each array in the `ArrayList` and get one element from each array.

So for example if one array was `"hello; are; today"` and another was `"how; you;"` then I want to retrieve it as `"hello how are you today"` (ie. one element from each array).

I can't think of a way to do this.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your ArrayLists should contain arrays of Strings? That essentially translates to a 2 dimensional list of Strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
int currentIndex = 0;
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
boolean arraysHaveMoreElements = true;
while (arraysHaveMoreElements) {
    arraysHaveMoreElements = false;
    for (String[] array : file) {
        if (array.length > currentIndex) {
            b.append(array[currentIndex];
            arraysHaveMoreElements = true;
        }
    }
    currentIndex++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not too difficult - under the assumption, that all rows have equal size!!

```
private void dumpColumnwise() {

  // generate test input
  // String[] firstRow = {"a00", "a01", "a02"};
  // String[] secondRow = {"a10", "a11", "a12"};
  String[] firstRow = "a00;a01;a02".split(";");
  String[] secondRow = "a10;a11;a12".split(";");

  List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<String[]>();
  rows.add(firstRow);
  rows.add(secondRow);

  // get longest row
  int numberOfColumns = 0;
  for (String[] row:rows) {
    numberOfColumns = Math.max(numberOfColumns, row.length);
  }

  int numberOfRows = rows.size();
  for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; colunm++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++) {
      String[] row = rows.get(row);
      if (column < row.length) {
        System.out.printf(" %s", rows.get(row)[column]);
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

<strike>Room for improvement: allow input data with different row lengths. In this case you have to (1) determine the longest row and (2) test if the column index is valid for the actual row.</strike> ... done.

Answer (score 0):

to read an array list we can use iterator interface.` 
using iterator we can go through the array list.
this is just an example code.

```
public static void  main(String []args)
   {
      ArrayList<String[]>  list=new ArrayList<>();
      String arr1[]={"hello","are","today"};
        String arr2[]={"how","you"};
        list.add(arr1);
        list.add(arr2);
       Iterator<String[]> it = list.iterator();
         while(it.hasNext())
         {
             String[] temp=it.next();
             System.out.print(temp[0]+" ");

         }



   }`
```

output= hello how;